# How to concatenate two ComplexMatrix?

Tags: ojalgo

I want to concatenate two ComplexMatrix (lib ojAlgo) of size (n rows1, n columns) and size (n rows2, n columns) to a matrix of size (n rows1 + n rows2, n columns).

I managed to cut a matrix in half with limits(n Rows/2,-1) and offset(nRows/2,0) but I can't find the functions to do the opposite.
If it were a primitive matrix I would create a DenseReceiver of size (nRows1+nRows2, nColumn) and fill this row by row to have my concatenate Matrix, though maybe there exist more efficient solutions. However, for ComplexMatrix I didn't find the equivalent, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods:

```
this.left(other);
this.right(other);
this.above(other);
this.below(other);
```